# Console Error, need to remove a specific character

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I know the title may be confusing, but my problem seems fairly easy.

I'm trying to remove a specific character "#".

[This is how it currently logs (Click Here = Image)](https://i.gyazo.com/c56120b9417514533fe9b3f5c0913b4f.png)
I'm trying to simply remove the "#" character so when it logs to the console it won't have the # in front of the text.

I've tried adding this before the break.

var color = stroke.split("#");
but it didn't work.

Here is my code

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://colorillo.com/byjy.inline.svg");
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    this.responseText.trim(),
    "image/svg+xml"
);
// Get all polylines as strings
let lines = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline');
// Loop over all lines
for(let line of lines) {
    // --- OPTIONAL START ---

    //See Bruce'es comment (rgb() as output)
    let stroke = line.style.stroke;
    //let size = line.style.stroke-width;  -- Disabled
    // --- OR ---

    // Loop over all styles of this line (output same as input [hex])
    for(let style of line.getAttribute('style').split(';')) {
        // Get name & value
        let valueOffset = style.indexOf(':');
        // Check if name equal to 'stroke'
        if(style.substr(0, valueOffset).trim() === 'stroke') {
            // Save stroke value
            stroke = style.substr(valueOffset + 1).trim();
            // Break out of the loop (we don't have to search further)
            stroke.split("#"); // Here is what I've tried.
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(stroke)
}
});
xhr.send();
```

Comment: `break;` ???  that is not going to reach that line. Also split does not remove anything, it makes an array.

Comment: OH SORRY!, I mean't to put it before the break.

Comment: Can you help me? I just need the "#" character to be removed somehow when it logs.

Comment: and split does nothing to the string. Use replace https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: you just need the `#` character removed? Why not just use `stroke.replace('#',''); //two single quotes` ?

Comment: Good stuff guys. I'm new with JavaScript still. Thanks for this. It fixed my error.

Comment: no worries. Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change stroke.split("#") to

```
stroke.replace('#','');
```

This will remove the first '#' in the string.

You can confirm by adding

```
console.log('BEFORE: '+stroke);
```

before that line, and

```
console.log('AFTER: '+stroke);
```

after it.  Then check your console.log output in Dev Tools (or equivalent).

Comment: Can you help me again. You see the ``let size = line.style.stroke-width;`` in the script. I'm trying to do the same there as the ``let stroke = line.style.stroke;``. It doesn't work though. It says width is not defined. I think it's because of the "-" is there anyway to fix that sir?

Comment: I've tried adding the attribute's name after the style just like the stroke.

Comment: try either line.style.strokeWidth or line.style['stroke-width']

Comment: styles are often referenced this way since saying something like line.style.stroke-width actually means line.style.stroke MINUS width .  To get around that, using the bracketed method will let you use the exact name 'stroke-width'.. also the first bracket is like it's own dot, so don't put an extra dot there.  Oh, and do include the quotes (can be single, double, backticks, etc but has to be quoted like I just showed).  Usually hyphenated names from styles and html are rechristened in JS by removing the hyphen/minus sign and capitalizing the first letter of the second word.

Comment: For example, an elements style 'background-color' which might be in CSS like #mydiv { background-color: black } can be referenced as document.getElementById('mydiv').style.backgroundColor OR document.getElementById('mydiv').style['background-color'] in JavaScript. In the second case, you can even use a variable with the string 'background-color' like var x='background-color'; document.getElementById('mydiv').style[x] = 'black';

Comment: @ownslo Did this work for you?  It is a valid js reference to the css prop;  wondering if there was something different in your reference as I never heard back from you.  If it did work, please thumbs up.  If it did not directly work, but led you to a solution, please thumbs up and elaborate in order to help others.